# WPF ComboBox SelectionChanged and DropDownClosed events is not working

Tags: wpf, events, combobox, selectionchanged

I am trying to call method by linking it to the Selection changed event and DropDownClosed event of the Combobox in WPF but when i change the item in combobox it is not calling the function it suppose to (in my case OnMyComboBoxChanged1 and OnMyComboBoxChanged2).

> MainWindow.xaml.cs

```js
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public List<string > NameOfPerson { get; set; }
        public string SelectedComboBoxItem { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NameOfPerson = new List<string>();
            NameOfPerson.Add("Ram");
            NameOfPerson.Add("Sita");
            NameOfPerson.Add("Hari");
            NameOfPerson.Add("Kumar");
            NameOfPerson.Add("Jay");
            NameOfPerson.Add("Bikash");
            MyComboBox.ItemsSource = NameOfPerson;
           this.MyComboBox.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(OnMyComboBoxChanged1);
           this.MyComboBox.DropDownClosed += new System.EventHandler(OnMyComboBoxChanged2);
        }

        private void OnMyComboBoxChanged1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedComboBoxItem = this.MyComboBox.Text;
        }
        private void OnMyComboBoxChanged2(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedComboBoxItem = this.MyComboBox.Text;
        }

    }
```

> XAML

```html
 <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Combobox"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" Margin="50,0,0,0" Width="80"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <Label Content="The selected item is : "/>
            <Label Content="{Binding SelectedComboBoxItem}"/> 
        </StackPanel>
       
    </StackPanel>
```

Thank you for the Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the label won't update because nothing is telling it to update - there is no automatic notification for standard C# properties.

You need to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) for your SelectedComboBoxItem property, or even better switch to the [`MVVM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) design pattern.

The alternative is to use direct data binding

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName="MyComboBox", Path=SelectedItem}" />
```

This works because properties of controls are (usually) [`DependencyProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview) which do provide notification of changes.

**Edit after comment**

Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then ... the following code works fine for me.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var NameOfPerson = new List<string>();
    NameOfPerson.Add("Ram");
    NameOfPerson.Add("Sita");
    NameOfPerson.Add("Hari");
    NameOfPerson.Add("Kumar");
    NameOfPerson.Add("Jay");
    NameOfPerson.Add("Bikash");
    MyComboBox.ItemsSource = NameOfPerson;

    MyComboBox.SelectionChanged += (s,e) => MyComboBoxOnSelectionChanged();
}

private void MyComboBoxOnSelectionChanged()
{
    SelectedComboBoxItem = MyComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    Debugger.Break(); // proof that the event handler is being called
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, it seems my question was not clear but the problem i am trying to solve is that...from this statement `this.MyComboBox.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(OnMyComboBoxChanged1);` from what i believe is the event  SelectionChanged  should call the method tiedup to it but it doesnot. In fact I tried using breakpoint in this statement and check if the event fires if i change the item in combobox but it doesnot. I will also try as you suggested

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it and the methods are called. The problem is probably that you use the wrong property to retrieve the selected item. Try this instead:

```
SelectedComboBoxItem = this.MyComboBox.SelectedItem as string;
```

Comment: I am sorry, it seems my question was not clear but the problem i am trying to solve is that...from this statement `this.MyComboBox.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(OnMyComboBoxChanged1);` from what i believe is the event  SelectionChanged  should call the method tiedup to it but it doesnot. In fact I tried using breakpoint in this statement and check if the event fires if i change the item in combobox but it doesnot. I will also try as you suggested

Comment: I have tried your code and the events are called. `SelectionChanged` first, `DropDownClosed` second. I've suggested to use `SelectedItem` for SelectionChanged, because this event is called before setting Text. For DropDownClose, it is ok to use Text because it is set by the time this event handler is called.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 2 things.

1. You should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) Interface with a backing field to your property SelectedComboBoxItem.
2. You need to set DataContext to your class like this.

   this.DataContext = this;

Comment: I am sorry, it seems my question was not clear but the problem i am trying to solve is that...from this statement `this.MyComboBox.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(OnMyComboBoxChanged1);` from what i believe is the event  SelectionChanged  should call the method tiedup to it but it doesnot. In fact I tried using breakpoint in this statement and check if the event fires if i change the item in combobox but it doesnot. I will also try as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Bellow is the answer and the working code just in case if someone needs it

> MainWindow.xaml.cs

```js
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Combobox
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public List<string> NameOfPerson { get; set; }
        private string _SelectedComboBoxItem;
        public string SelectedComboBoxItem
        {
            get
            {
                return _SelectedComboBoxItem;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_SelectedComboBoxItem == value)
                    return;
                _SelectedComboBoxItem = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedComboBoxItem)));
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            NameOfPerson = new List<string>();
            NameOfPerson.Add("Ram");
            NameOfPerson.Add("Sita");
            NameOfPerson.Add("Hari");
            NameOfPerson.Add("Kumar");
            NameOfPerson.Add("Jay");
            NameOfPerson.Add("Bikash");
            MyComboBox.ItemsSource = NameOfPerson;
            this.MyComboBox.SelectionChanged += OnMyComboBoxChanged1;
            this.MyComboBox.DropDownClosed += OnMyComboBoxChanged2;
        }


        private void OnMyComboBoxChanged1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedComboBoxItem = this.MyComboBox.SelectedItem as string;
        }
        private void OnMyComboBoxChanged2(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedComboBoxItem = this.MyComboBox.Text;
            Debugger.Break();
        }

    }

}
```

> XAML

```html
<Window x:Class="Combobox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Combobox"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="300">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Combobox"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" Margin="50,0,0,0" Width="80"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <Label Content="The selected item is : "/>
            <Label Content="{Binding SelectedComboBoxItem}"  />
        </StackPanel>
       
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```